# How can I disable KeyboardPan in OL 6

Tags: openlayers-6

I'm new to OL and only found examples for Version 3
I tried `interactions: defaultInteractions().extend(KeyboardPan.setActive = false),`, but that didn't work and `interactions: new Collection(),` but that disabled all interations.

Answer (score 0):

```
interactions: defaultInteractions({keyboard: false})
```

will remove both KeyboardPan and KeyboardZoom.

For KeyboardZoom without KeyboardPan you will need

```
interactions: defaultInteractions({keyboard: false}).extend([new KeyboardZoom()])
```

Comment: Thanks!, Works now